# h5bp build script - update css reference automatically?

Tags: html5boilerplate

When I build my h5bp project, the published html files do not include an updated reference to the versioned css file (they still point to 'css/style.css' rather than the newly made css file).  The index.html file is the one exception to this.

Is there a step that I am missing while creating the site or while running `$ ant build`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a mismatch between the stable h5bp version and the current version of their ant-build script. The ant-build script assumes a different directory layout for JS files.

Anyway, they've included some compatibility options in **"/build/config/project.properties"**. Look for the paragraph starting with **"# Compatibility with older versions of html5boilerplate"**, uncomment the following lines and build again. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that.  At this point I've figured out my own build script that piggy backs on the ant-build to keep everything updated.  Your solution would have been a bit faster but maybe not as fun :)